# Getting the top 2 amount with the most recent dates

Tags: date, sql-server-2016

My original code was taking all transactions in the last 12 months and compare the top two highest single transaction.

If the highest single gift within that time period is more than two times greater than the 2nd largest single transaction, take the 2nd highest single gift. If the #1 single highest gift is not two times greater, it is used.

I found I need to use the most recent dates with the top 2 amount with the above rules. If I use the last 12 months, I'm not getting all the amount value I need.

How do I change the where statement to get the most recent dates instead of the last 12 months from the current current date.

Input Values

```
account number, date, and transaction amount.  
7428, 01262018, 2
7428, 12302018, 5
16988 02142016, 100
16988 01152016, 25
22450 04191971, 8
22450 08291971, 10
```

Results

```
AccountNumber   Number  Amount
------------------------------
7428    2   5.00
16988   2   25.00
22450   2   10.00
26997   2   10.00
27316   2   25.00
27365   2   25.00
28620   2   10.00
28951   2   10.00
29905   2   5.00
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @start_date date
DECLARE @end_date date

SET @start_date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
SET @end_date = GETDATE()

SELECT
    AccountNumber, 
    COUNT(amount) as Number, 
    CASE 
       WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN amount END) > MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN amount END) * 2
          THEN MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN amount END) 
          ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN amount END) 
    END AS Amount 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY amount DESC) AS row_num
     FROM 
         dbo.[T01_TransactionMaster]
     WHERE 
         date >= @start_date AND date < @end_date) AS tt
WHERE 
    row_num IN (1, 2) 
    AND amount > 0 
    -- AND AccountNumber = 301692
GROUP BY 
    AccountNumber
```

Comment: In addition to showing the current results, it would help to see the desired results, and also some input data.

Comment: I need the date on the where statement to pull a range from 12 months back from the most resent translation date.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to change this statement  where date >= start_date AND date < end_date.   So that is will pull from 12 months back from most resent transaction date.